# Is e.g. 我与的朋友在二月份去中国 a colloquial way to say "I'm going to China with my friends in Feburary"?

Tags: translation

Is this a colloquial way to say this?

> 我与的朋友在二月份去中国

or what about

> 我二月份与的朋友在去中国

Comment: The second one is better but don't need that 的

Comment: Nor do we need that 在

Comment: If I dont need to use 在, how to I indicate that Im going to go somewhere.. like Im planning on it, or that Im definitely doing it? Hui? 会
在 is used with location and when indicating you're currently doing something, correct?

Comment: @KevinPrice, 在二月 in Chinese sounds more like that it already passed, not quite likely in the future. you could put 我二月份要和（几个）朋友去中国。

Comment: @KevinPrice: you could use 要 to indicate 'be going to'.

Comment: so here the use of 我要和朋友  is more translated to im going with friends and is more colloquial than saying 我要与朋友?? 

Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: 我要和朋友 is more casual way to say it.

Answer (score 4):

1. First, 的 is not needed and doesn't make sense. Omit it altogether (or make it 我的朋友).
2. Second, 在 is to express what is happening right now. It is close to "is doing ~" in English (e.g. 我在看书。). If you talk about what will happen in the future, 要 should be the word for it. So replace 在 with 要.

So, the one answer should be:

> 我二月份要与朋友去中国。

Answer (score 1):

Actually, both "我与的朋友在二月份去中国" and "我二月份与的朋友在去中国" are not correct.

If you emphasize "I am going to", you can use

> "我将在二月与我的朋友去中国"

If you emphasize "in February", you can use

> "二月份我将与我的朋友去中国"

If you emphasize "with my friends", you can use

> "我将与我的朋友在二月时去中国"

Comment: What is the use of 将在  here?

Comment: @KevinPrice, "我二月要和朋友去中国" is the most colloquial way I think.

Comment: @KevinPrice, "在" uses in "doing something" and "将在" means "be going to"

Comment: so 将在 is like "Im going to be at" or "im going to be in"? and 将去 is like "Im going to go" ???

Comment: 将去 is like "I'm going to go". But when you use "将在", here "将" means "be going to" and "在" means " 'in'  February "

Comment: 将 + Verb: I am going to do something, like "我将去中国" I am going to China

Comment: 将在 + Time + Verbs: I am going to do something in "TIME", like 我将在二月去中国  I am going to China in February.

Comment: But if you want the most colloquial way, it is "我二月要和朋友去中国"

Answer (score 0):

的朋友 doesn't make sense, should be 我的朋友, 我的 = my.

我与我的朋友在二月份去中国 is OK, though 我和我的朋友二月份去中国/二月份我和我的朋友去中国 would be more natural, and the 我的 can also be ommitted.

我二月份与我的朋友在去中国 is not understandable.